# How to copy some ElasticSearch data to a new domain

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elk

Can someone please help me out with some pointers as to how can I copy data from one ELK (AWS Elastic Service) domain to another ?

Comment: Have you took a look at reindex feature? : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html

Comment: Yes I did. Although as far as I understand that API , reindex copies from one index to another in SAME domain. In my case I am trying to copy data from one index to another in two different domains

Comment: Well reindex support it, look at the remote part. You can also use snapshort.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [reindex](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html) api and consider your domain as 2 differents clusters.

For example, a request that you will run on your domain targeted (consider as new cluser that will be received the index data from old cluster named here *domainA*):

```
POST _reindex?wait_for_completion=false
{
  "source": {
    "remote": {
      "host": "http://mydomainA:9200/"
    },
    "index": "myindex-2021",
    "query": {
      "match_all": {}
    }
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "myindex-2021"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you YLR for the details. I am using AWS managed ELK instance and I am getting below error. Any idea what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: {
  "error" : "no handler found for uri [/https://myenpoint/_reindex?pretty=true&scroll=10h&wait_for_completion=false] and method [POST]"
}

Comment: This is my code which I am executing in Kibana 
POST <local-domain-endpoint>/_reindex
{
  "source": {
    "remote": {
      "host": "https://remote-domain-endpoint:443"
    },
    "index": "remote_index",
    "query": {
      "match": {
        "field_name": "text"
      }
    }
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "local_index"
  }
}

Comment: Ok, I guess you must look this doc to have more details to use reindex in AWS managed ELK : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/remote-reindex.html

Comment: Yes I am following exact same link although when I try to execute the query I am getting "no handler found for uri"

Comment: One quick question 

Is "local-domain-endpoint" is fully qualified URL like https://vpc-domain-name..us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com" ??